# Predicting spherical k-Means clusters for new data points

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, prediction

I am performing a spherical k-Means clustering in R using skmeans package. My goal is to use a moderate number of validated data points to define the clusters and after that to assign all the rest of the data points to these clusters.

As far as I have understood, this could be done using the 'cl_predict' function in 'clue' package. For some reason the output is all NA's. Does anyone know how this can get done?

Here is a small example (the real data to be clustered consist of approximately 2 million observations and 50 variables).

```
#invoke necessary packages
library("skmeans")
library("clue")
#generate test data
testGrid<-(seq(-10,10,by=1)) 
pointsToCluster<-merge(data.frame(x=testGrid[-11]),
data.frame(y=testGrid[-11]))
plot(pointsToCluster)
#perform spherical clustering
sClustOut<-skmeans(as.matrix(pointsToCluster[,1:2]),4)
plot(pointsToCluster,col=sClustOut$cluster)
#predict clusters for new data points
newDataPoints<-matrix(c(1.3,2.1,3.1,5.9),ncol=2)
cl_predict(sClustOut,newDataPoints)
```